# No logro actualizar la Api Google Maps Javascript con la nueva clave

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, script

buenas noches, tenia andando en un sistema de 2015 los mapas de google correctamente, incluso me llevaba a una ubicación dada por un determinado inmueble y me la seleccionaba en el mapa, reflotando este sistema me doy con que google cambio su política y ahora pide una tarjeta de crédito para darte la clave de la api, la conseguí y actualice la cadena src para la conexión al mapa y me doy con que ya no anda mas, ni muestra ningún mapa.

Dejo codigo html y javascript para ver si me pueden orientar. gracias!
Utilizo Visual Studio 2017.

[image: Acá el código HTML donde se muestra el mapa y lo que recibe como parámetro...]

Aca abajo la parte de JS con los Scripts... ( La cadena src es la nueva que me provee google )

```js
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MICLAVE&callback=initMap"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
@*Clave: MICLAVE*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        if ('#address' != null) {
            {
                var addres = $('#address').val();
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addres }, geocodeResult);
            }

        }
        else exit

    });
    function geocodeResult(results, status) {
        // Verificamos el estatus
        if (status == 'OK') {
            // Si hay resultados encontrados, centramos y repintamos el mapa
            // esto para eliminar cualquier pin antes puesto
            var mapOptions = {
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas").get(0), mapOptions);
            // fitBounds acercará el mapa con el zoom adecuado de acuerdo a lo buscado
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            // Dibujamos un marcador con la ubicación del primer resultado obtenido
            var markerOptions = { position: results[0].geometry.location, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE }
            var lati = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longi = results[0].geometry.location.lng();



            $.post('/Inmuebles/latLon/', { lat: lati, lng: longi });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            marker.setMap(map);
        } else {
            // En caso de no haber resultados o que haya ocurrido un error
            // lanzamos un mensaje con el error
            //alert("Geocoding no tuvo éxito debido a: " + status);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Las llaves de API de Google son protegidas con unas reglas tipo "firewall" para evitar que alguien haga uso indiscriminado de la llave de alguien más. Te recomiendo que revises dicha configuración en el portal de Google para determinar que no se esté bloqueando o que le des los permisos adecuados. Incluso puedes indicar que la llave pueda ser utilizada de manera pública por cualquiera (de manera temporal, obviamente) para determinar que sí funciona y que el problema va por ahí.

Comment: Ya esta de manera publica y aun asi no me aparece el mapa